# How to group row with unique value in knime?

Tags: excel, knime

I am interested in data science and I am quite new to knime. I have a question about the grouping the data in Excel. I have an xlsx file with two columns. in the xlsx file there is information about 2000 people. This informations titles are in the column A, and infos are in the column B . in data, when the information of one person is completed, the order of the other person's data begins. There are about 10 unique title in the A column. People have some of these titles, maybe some people have all. What I want to do is to convert these data in columns by unique titles in column A and write the data in column B into rows. But how?

First picture is how my data looks like and Second picture is what i want to do:
[image: That is how my data looks]:
[image: That is what i want]

Comment: In HiTS, I had a node for this, [Pivot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aborg0/hits/master/com.mind_era.knime.util/html/nodes/Pivot.html), check the examples. As your groups have different lengths, it is not possible to do the easier group loop start, transpose, group loop end solution. Maybe Python, R or something else can help here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a column to your data that identifies which group each row belongs to, then you can use the Pivot node to transform it in the way you want.

The easiest place to do that is in Excel, using a formula that returns the value of the cell above, plus 1 if the cell in column A equals "name" - giving a number that increments by 1 for each change of name.

If you can't change the Excel source, the neatest way of doing it in KNIME would be with a Java, R or Python snippet as Gábor suggests. However if you really want to do it in pure KNIME, here's a slow and elaborate workflow:

[image: KNIME workflow to add group IDs]

The nodes need to be configured as follows:

- **Excel Reader** returns a table with columns `Col0` and `Col1`
- **One to Many** includes `Col0` but excludes `Col1` - this gives us a `name` column containing 1 whenever `Col0` is `name` (also columns for each of the other possible values, but we won't use these)
- **Create Table Structure** creates 1 integer column named `Group 0`
- **Column Appender** is configured for non-identical row keys and table lengths, and to use row keys from the first table
- **Missing Value** replaces missing number values with the fixed value 0

At this point the table should look like:

[image: KNIME table]

Inside the recursive loop,

- **Math Formula** replaces column `Group 0` with the formula `$Group 0$+$${Iname}$$` - which takes the previous value of `Group 0` and adds the value of `name` from the first row of the current iteration of the table (via **Table Row to Variable**)
- **Row Splitter** is configured to 'Include rows by number' and outputs rows 2 - end to the upper port and row 1 to the lower port.

The `Group 0` column now contains a value that increments on each name:

[image: KNIME table 2]

Finally the **Pivoting** node is configured to group on `Group 0`, pivot on `Col0` and aggregate on `Col1` by the `First` method, giving:

[image: KNIME table 3]

which you can filter, reorder etc as you need.

It ought to be possible to leave out the One to Many and simply configure Math Formula to add 1 each time the variable for `Col0` equals 'name', but I couldn't get that to work first time so I left it as it is.

Note that this will only work if `name` is always the first row for each person in the table, but I don't see how you could unambiguously interpret the data if it wasn't.

If anyone has a faster or more concise KNIME implementation I'd be happy to see it!